# Remove duplicate element from the list with remove method without using another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lis3 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
for i in range(len(lis3)):
    counter = 0
    for j in range(len(lis3)):
        if lis3[i] == lis3[j]:
            counter += 1
            if counter > 2:
                lis3.remove(lis3[j])
```

i try to remove duplicate element from the list but i get the error index out of range can anyone fix this problem why i am getting this error

i try with while and many other approach but i get same error if run loop -1 time the also same error and i don't want to use another list for the removing element

Comment: What shall the result be? And please don't make the question hard to read. Add punctuation and use upper case letters appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding specifically your implementation, this is what went wrong and what you can do to fix it:

1. Replace the outer `for`-loop with a `while`-loop. The `for`-loop evaluates `range(len(lis3))` only once (at the start of the loop). Since the size of your list varies inside the loop, it's not an accurate iteration and will fail with an `IndexError`:

```py
lis3 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]

i = 0
while i < len(lis3):
    # ...

    i += 1
```

2. Keep your `counter` variable initializing it to zero:

```py
lis3 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]

i = 0
while i < len(lis3):
    counter = 0

    # ...

    i += 1
```

3. Replace the inner `for`-loop also with a `while`-loop for the same reason mentioned above. However, you don't need to initialize `j` to zero, you can initialize it to the next index after `i`, otherwise you'll compare with elements that you've already visited by the outer loop:

```py
lis3 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]

i = 0
while i < len(lis3):
    counter = 0

    j = i + 1
    while j < len(lis3):
        # ...
 
        j += 1

    i += 1
```

4. Keep the same comparison using `counter` you're doing. However, since you're iterating the list once per unique element, you need to compare if `counter` is one or more:

```py
lis3 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]

i = 0
while i < len(lis3):
    counter = 0

    j = i + 1
    while j < len(lis3):
        if lis3[i] == lis3[j]:
            counter += 1
            if counter >= 1:
                # ...
 
        j += 1

    i += 1
```

5. Finally, if another element is found, you can remove by index (using `pop`) instead of by element (using `remove`). Since you're removing the element, you need to go back one position on your iteration:

```py
lis3 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]

i = 0
while i < len(lis3):
    counter = 0

    j = i + 1
    while j < len(lis3):
        if lis3[i] == lis3[j]:
            counter += 1
            if counter >= 1:
                lis3.pop(j)
                j -= 1
 
        j += 1

    i += 1
```

---

With this approach, you don't even need the `counter` variable:

```py
lis3 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]

i = 0
while i < len(lis3):
    j = i + 1
    while j < len(lis3):
        if lis3[i] == lis3[j]:
            lis3.pop(j)
            j -= 1

        j += 1

    i += 1
```

---

To understand this implementation better, I recommend using the  variable visualizer of [Python Tutor](https://pythontutor.com/python-compiler.html).

Comment: thanks actually i want really do this , i don't want to use set or any other approach thanks again

Comment: @Jamee Nice! You can always click on the checkmark at the left of the answer to accept the one that most helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, *removing* duplicate elements from a list can be inefficient and cumbersome; adding [unnecessary complexity to the code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python). This is why I am not addressing your question directly; but rather, providing a couple of other, more efficient and light-weight approaches:

#### Option 1) The long (inefficient) way:

This option is long-hand and rather inefficient as the new list is checked for *each* element in the source list, but illustrates an approach of creating *new* list containing only unique elements from the source - as opposed to trying to remove the duplicate values.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
new = []

for i in l:
    if i not in new:
        new.append(i)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(new)
[1, 2, 3]
```

#### Option 2) Using `set`:

Using a `set`.  By mathematical definition, a 'set' contains only unique values. Therefore, using Python's `set()` function subsets and iterable to only its unique elements. *However* ... while this approach is the most efficient of the options, it should only be used if *order does not need to be preserved*.

```
>>> list(set(l))
[1, 2, 3]
```

#### Option 3) Using `dict`:

As helpfully and cleverly mentioned by @AndreKesely the list can be converted into a dictionary with the list elements as keys. Since dictionary keys must be unique ... well, there we go! An advantage of this solution is that *order is retained*.

```
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(l))
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

#### Timings:

If you're interested in the efficiency of each method, here are the benchmarks. In these cases, the tested list contains 1,000,000 integers between 0 and 10, inclusive.

Option 1): **201 ms** ± 17.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Option 2): **27.7 ms** ± 1.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Option 3): **49.2 ms** ± 234 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: Though the topic says *"with remove method without using another list"* and the text also says *"i don't want to use another list"*...

Comment: And if all you're doing is answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7961363/12671057), you should've instead voted to close this as duplicate.

Comment: Meh, they don't even tell us the expected result, and their "remove if count > 2" suggests that they want to keep up to 2 of each value. Maybe they're trying [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array-ii/description/).

Comment: Voting isn't about time spent, intentions or fairness. It's about usefulness regarding the question.